# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.spongycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter

Tags: java, android, encryption, spongycastle

I am using spongy castle library and it works well on API 16+. But I get this error on api level<16;

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.spongycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter
```

I added reference like below;

```
compile 'ch.dissem.jabit:jabit-cryptography-spongy:2.0.4'
compile 'ch.dissem.jabit:jabit-cryptography-bouncy:1.0.1'
```

I reviewed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39705559/6678241) but it is not working for me. Additionally I added required commands on my pro-guard file and it works on api 16+ great.

Comment: I enabled multidex, it worked.